# Use an apostrophe to shorten word?

Tags: apostrophe

Is it grammatically correct to be able to shorten the word "manicures" to "mani's", omitting "cure" with an *apostrophe*?

Comment: Do you think "mani's" would be understood as "manicures"?

Comment: The google finds about four times as many "manis" as "mani's."

Comment: Many what? Who is [Ma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mani_%28prophet%29)[ni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ice_Age_characters#Manny)?

Comment: Well mani-pedi is somewhat to my surprise actually a word known to the Merriam-Webster and the OED (which is looking for citations before 1972 btw.), but neither seems to know mani as a shortening for manicure.

Comment: *Mani-pedi* is certainly not in the online OED. Did you mean some other dictionary calling itself the *Oxford Dictionary*? What in the world is a 'mani-pedi'? Is it a combined manicure-pedicure service of some sort?

Comment: I think it depends on context too. In and of itself, 'mani' means little to many people. Place it on a beauty salons window however, it now has context and meaning. It also helps that the target audience would already understand the terminology as from what I understand, many already use the shortened term 'mani'. However I would not know how to pluralise it without it falling into the ownership trap. Maybe forget the apostrophe, and leave it to interpretation, I think its a lose-lose situation on the grammar front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, especially as "mani's" would normally be read as "belonging to mani". This looks like what's called a greengrocer's apostrophe: signs advertising "pear's" (incorrect, should just be pears).

The only place where apostrophe abbreviation is commonly used is on road signs, where it tends to be in the middle or near the start of the word. For example, http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-an-apostrophe-used-as-an-abbreviation-on-a-road-sign-78038341.html shows "Leam'ton" for Leamington. "B'ham" for Birmingham would be another example.